# Why can't file_get_contents() exchange code for token with Facebook oauth.

Tags: facebook, oauth, file-get-contents

I cannot exchange code for token using the following code:

```
extract($_GET);
$url=urlencode('http://'.DOMAIN.'/admin/');
$app_id=FB_APPID;
$fb_token=FB_TOKEN;
$secret=FB_SECRET;

if(SEND_NEWS_TO_FB){
    if($code=='none'){
            $state=rand(100000000,9999999999999999999);
            $_SESSION['state']=$state;
            $script="
            <script type='text/javascript'>
                    var scope=encodeURI('publish_stream,user_status');
                    var app_id=$app_id;
                    var state=$state;
                    var url=$js_url;
                    window.location.href='https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?                                                                                            client_id='+app_id+'&redirect_uri='+url+'&scope='+scope+'&state='+state;

            </script>";
            echo $script;
    }



if($code!='none' && $_SESSION['state']==$state && $_SESSION['fb_token']!=1){
            $_SESSION['fb_token']=1;
            $token_url="https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
            ."client_id=" .$app_id
            ."&redirect_uri=" .$url
            ."&client_secret=" .$secret
            ."&code=" .$code;
            $response = file_get_contents($token_url);
            $params = null;
            parse_str($response, $params);
            $token=$params['access_token'];
            $qry="UPDATE `settings` SET `FB_token`='$token'";
            $result=mysql_query($qry);
        }
```

Placing the returned $token_url in my browser gives me a page with the token and expiration. Running the script returns a very vague "sorry, there was a problem" message. Almost all of the threads I have seen with problems doing this have been due to differences in the redirect uri's, but both the login and token request get the uri from the exact same place.

Comment: i notice you are missing the `scope` and the `grant_type` parameters. maybe try adding these and see if it works? (`grant_type` must be `authorization_code` when obtaining the access token)

Comment: The formatting got a little mucked on the login section     `client_id='+app_id+'&redirect_uri='+url+'&scope='+scope+'&state='+state;` Is pushed way off to the right in the login url. So I did use `scope`. Do you mean that scope should be passed for the code/token exchange also? And where did you find documentation for `grant_type` in serverside flow? I have not been able to find any documentation on the serverside oauth process aside from (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/).

Answer (score 0):

There was a whitespace between the app_id value and '&redirect_url'. FYI, your browser (at least chromium) will urlencode the whitespace automatically which is why the url will work fine in the browser. I still am not sure how the space is there, but urlencode() fixes it for now.